# sending information from one controller to another

Tags: controllers, ajax, action

I am hoping to link together some controller actions if a certain quote option is selected.  More specifically, when a coupon code is activated and the user wishes to use their gift card I want to resend the coupon code information back to the coupon controller.

Is it possible to link together controllers in such a manner?  If so, how?  Both of these controller actions normally response to ajax requests.

Comment: I think you should use a Helper for this instead of your approach.

Comment: @mbalparda So I will call the helper from the first controller and this helper will interact with the second?

Comment: No, you should put the logic in your helper class and pass the objects you need in the call of the Helper's method.

Comment: @mbalpard thanks, I'll let you know if I run into any other confusions.

Comment: I added this as an answer. If this helped you resolve your issue mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two controllers up should call a Helper and put your logic in there. Also you should pass the objects you need for your logic in the helper call as parameters. To complete the answer, a model can also be the solution for your issue. You should see if you will be formatting code or interacting with data to see which class type suits you better.